# How to Limit Elements on a Screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 boxes, (which will later be 9), in which I want there to be a total of 3 on screen at all times, excluding mobile. The remainder who are not on screen will be moved to the right end of the box line, but be unseen. I have looked around for a method to accomplish this via HTML & CSS and have found none. Is there a way to do this with HTML, CSS, or JS?

```css
.bioSlider {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 390px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.slideImage {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.slideImage img {
  object-fit: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.quoteText {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: italic;
  word-break: break-all;
  padding: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.detailBox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 9px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.slideImage:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 50%;
}

.slideImage:hover .quoteText {
  opacity: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- Cadet Slider -->
  <ul class='bioSlider'>
    <li class='cadetOne'>
      <div class='box'>
        <div class='slideImage'>
          <img src='/Images/Red_Card.png' alt=''>
          <div class='overlay'> </div>
          <div class='bodyTextContainer'>
            <p class='quoteText'>"Poopoopeepee"</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='detailBox'>
          <div class='subHeaderTextContainer'>
            <h3 class='subHeaderText_1'>Battalion CDR <br> LTC Chase Hinson</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class='cadetTwo'>
      <div class='box'>
        <div class='slideImage'>
          <img src='/Images/Yellow_Card.png' alt=''>
          <div class='overlay'></div>
          <div class='bodyTextContainer'>
            <p class='quoteText'>"Poopoopeepee"</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='detailBox'>
          <div class='subHeaderTextContainer'>
            <h3 class='subHeaderText_1'>Battalion XO <br> MAJ Grayson Akins</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class='cadetThree'>
      <div class='box'>
        <div class='slideImage'>
          <img src='/Images/Blue_Card.png' alt=''>
          <div class='overlay'></div>
          <div class='bodyTextContainer'>
            <p class='quoteText'>"Poopoopeepee"</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='detailBox'>
          <div class='subHeaderTextContainer'>
            <h3 class='subHeaderText_1'>Battalion NCO <br> CSM Janecia Bass</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class='cadetFour'>
      <div class='box'>
        <div class='slideImage'>
          <img src='/Images/Green_Card.png' alt=''>
          <div class='overlay'></div>
          <div class='bodyTextContainer'>
            <p class='quoteText'>"Poopoopeepee"</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='detailBox'>
          <div class='subHeaderTextContainer'>
            <h3 class='subHeaderText_1'>Battalion S1 <br> CPT Lauren Newton</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You could make each box 33% of the screen by using `width:33vw`. If you place all boxes next to each other you'll only see 3.

Comment: I fixed your invalid HTML too